# Class 'Detection\MobileDetect' not found in

Tags: mobile, detect

composer require mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib

use use Detection\MobileDetect as Mobile_Detect;

$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

show me Class 'Detection\MobileDetect' not found, why?

thanks